# Unable to mount efs volume in minikube cluster

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, persistent-volumes, amazon-efs

I have the following resource configuration for my storage class, persistent volume and pv claim:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: efs-sc
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: efs-volume
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: REDACTED
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: efs-volume-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
```

Within my deployment spec I have the following configuration to mount the volume:

```
containers:
...
    volumeMounts:
      - name: efs-vol
        mountPath: /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content
        readOnly: false
...
volumes:
  - name: efs-vol
    persistentVolumeClaim: 
      claimName: efs-volume-claim
      readOnly: false
```

With kubectl configured to connect to minikube, I have run the following command to install the efs-csi driver:

```
kubectl apply -k "github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/deploy/kubernetes/overlays/stable/?ref=release-1.4"
```

When I run `kubectl get csidriver` I get the following response:

```
NAME              ATTACHREQUIRED   PODINFOONMOUNT   STORAGECAPACITY   TOKENREQUESTS   REQUIRESREPUBLISH   MODES        AGE
efs.csi.aws.com   false            false            false             <unset>         false               Persistent   22m
```

But when I apply my deployment config and my pods try to start up, they throw the following error:

```
MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "efs-volume" : kubernetes.io/csi: attacher.MountDevice failed to create newCsiDriverClient: driver name efs.csi.aws.com not found in the list of registered CSI drivers
```

Why is it unable to find the driver? Does minikube not support connections to EFS? Is there something I'm missing here? When I deploy my cluster config to EKS, everything seems to work fine - it's just with minikube that it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

I've tried running `minikube delete` to completely reset my minikube cluster and then reinstalled the driver and attempted to apply my config again but still got the same error

Comment: have you resolved the issue? I have very similar